# not working function with no errors

Tags: c++

I've implemented a function to display an avl tree after inserting nodes into it like this

```
template<class nodetype>
void AVLtree<nodetype>::display() const
{
 display(Proot);
}

template<class nodetype>
void AVLtree<nodetype>::display(Node<nodetype> * ptr) const
{
 if(ptr==0)
  return ;
 cout<<ptr->value<<" ";
 display(ptr->Pleft);
 display(ptr->Pright);
}
```

after compiling,there were no errors ,the program worked but nothing were printed on the screen

help me please....!!
thanks

Comment: I don't see a problem here.  How are you filling your tree?

Comment: no errors? what about warnings? any just because your code is syntactly correct doesn't mean it is sementacly correct :)

Comment: What is nodetype?  Are you sure it should print anything when sent to cout?

Answer (score 4):

(Assuming that your tree is built correctly). Screen output is normally line-buffered. You need to output `std::endl` to `std::cout` (or at least `'\n'` character) for something to appear on the screen.

Of course, if your tree is built incorrectly, the root pointer might be null and nothing would be printed for obvious reasons (just a guess).

Finally, even if your tree is built correctly, but all data (`ptr->value`) is, say, just strings that are empty (for example) or contain only whitespace, then no wonder you can't see anything on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

One technique I like to use is to add delimiters around debug strings:

```
cout << "-->" << ptr->value << "<--" << endl;
```

That way, it's easy to distinguish empty output from no output.

You may also want to add something that shows when your **entire** tree is empty:

```
void AVLtree<nodetype>::display() const
{
  if (Proot)
    display(Proot);
  else
    cout << "empty tree" << endl;
}
```

Comment: thank u,
this worked and "empty tree" was printed on the screen...
the wrong isn't in this function

Answer (score 1):

If you are printing on a console *window*, this function may be of use:

```
void Pause(void)
{
    cout << "\nPaused, press ENTER to continue.\n";
    cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
    return;
}
```

Call this function before any `exit` methods or `return` statements in `main`.

Comment: Although I personally prefer std::getline (in the <string> header) instead of cin.ignore:  std::string buffer; std::getline(cin, buffer);

Answer (score -2):

first of all you need a conceptual overhaul.. Who told you you can compare ptr with 0 ? 
Are you trying to suggest that a pointer if nullified is equal to 0 ? Thats totally wrong .. try this :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    int *p = NULL ;
    cout<<*p<<endl;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

and there your program crashes ... compare ptr with NULL instead of 0 ..

Comment: In C++, NULL and 0 are the same thing.  See http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#null for details from Stroustrup himself.  Also, using `int *p = 0;` and trying to dereference it using `*p` will cause the crash, too.

Comment: -1, sorry. `NULL` is exactly defined to be 0. After preprocessing, `if (p == NULL)` and `if (p == 0)` are indistinguishable.